# How do you find duplicates of questions?

Tags: discussion, search, duplicate-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are efficient ways to find duplicates on trilogy sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49458/what-are-efficient-ways-to-find-duplicates-on-trilogy-sites)

I asked the following question: [Shouldn’t consecutive days measure from midnight to midnight in the user’s time zone?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55406/shouldnt-consecutive-days-measure-from-midnight-to-midnight-in-the-users-time-z).  It turns out, it's a duplicate of [Change the definiton of a “day” to be localized for users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40119/change-the-definiton-of-a-day-to-be-localized-for-users), but notice none of the words I used to describe the problem match the other post (the other post doesn't mention consecutive days, among other things).

I hate writing duplicate posts (and losing points for duplicates)--how could I have found the other post?