# What to do when I know my question would be a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicate-questions, asking-questions

I'm searching for a solution for a problem/question I'm almost 100% sure was asked before **but I can't find it**.

It is a generic question, no way that it wasn't asked before but no matter how many ways I try to search I just can't find it.

I don't want to ask a dupe question only for the reason to get closed in 5 minutes, of course I would get my answer but this still sounds kinda selfish.

What should I do?

Comment: Maybe ask on the site's meta? In any case, I appreciate your conscientiousness here.

Comment: @DanBron I don't think meta is for that.

Comment: When you find a duplicate.  If your question is a duplicate then you get an answer, no harm, no foul

Comment: @totymedli It was an idea. Another is to use Google rather than SE's built-in search. For example: `site:philosophy.stackexchange.com Kant dualism` etc.

Comment: @DanBron I did that. I even tried to "ask" a question to see the "similar questions"  hint (because that still gives better result than the site search which is bad) but no luck.

Comment: totymedli, my **[power-user tip for finding duplicates](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/49595/98786)** is surprisingly effective.

Comment: @RobertCartaino Thanks but this doesn't answer my question. I'm not asking for how to search, I already did that, I just can't find the correct keywords that I should search with, I don't know what wording was used when somebody else asked this. My question is: should I still ask, or accept the failure and stay in silence?

Comment: Closing this question as a duplicate is kinda ironic...

Comment: @totymedli I was about to ask mine (exact same question), and I knew it would have been asked and answered already. Writing the title brought me here, but I almost did the same thing !

Comment: By the way it's weird, I find what I need much more when I write my question titles than when I search with the same keywords.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat I had the same experience. I never use the search functionality of the site. If I have to, I use the ask a question form's title field. It gives better results.